# Dynamic ContextMenuStrip

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, contextmenu, richtextbox

In my application I have 3 RichTextboxes, I created only one ContextMenuStrip because I don't like the idea of duplicate the same code of the same contextmenu and all the context menu options 3 times to use it with the other 2 Richs, the problem is I don't know how to use the same ContextMenu for the three RichTextBoxes.

For example one option of the ContextMenuStrip is "***Clear text***", then inside the procedure I need to specify the RichTextbox object name to clear the text:

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Clear_Text_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles MenuItem_Clear_Text.Click

    RichTextBox_Affix.Clear()

End Sub
```

How I can handle in a dynamic way the clear method in that sub for the other richtextboxes?

(I don't want to clear the text of the 3 richtextboxes at the same time, what I need is to know which RichTextBox opened the Contextmenu to clear the text only in that RichTextBox)

I've tried to find the necessary information about which RichTextBox called the contextmenu to handle the contextmenu procedure only for that RichTextBox, but I've found anything in the sender or "e" variables of the contextmenu CLICK event sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `ContextMenuStrip` from the given item, and the associated control (`RichTextBox`) from it. Sample code:

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Clear_Text_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles MenuItem_Clear_Text.Click

    Dim curContextMenu As ContextMenuStrip = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
    Dim curRTB As RichTextBox = DirectCast(curContextMenu.SourceControl, RichTextBox)
    curRTB.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I've simplified all in one line "sender.owner.SourceControl.Clear()" because I manage different user controls so I won't cast the richtextbox, if that line will not work with same efficacy or something just tell me, thanks again

Comment: @ElektroHacker My code relies on the proper types. Your version let VB.NET to assume many things. Your version cannot work with `Option Strict On` (what is something recommendable to have). I cannot give you exact numbers on how this will affect the performance but any assumption has associated time requirements (not too important in this case, this is true). In summary: the "proper way" is what I wrote, but what you are doing is basically maximising the VB permissiveness (with respect to other languages like C#) what I don't think that is too bad in this case. Do whatever you want :)